# NSFetchRequest predicate inconsistency iOS (NSFetchedResultsController) vs Mac (NSArrayController)

Tags: ios, macos, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

An inconsistency exists between NSFetchedResultsController on iOS and NSArrayController on Mac when using an NSFetchRequest with a predicate containing an attribute that is defined by the object class and not part of the entity attributes.

Consider a managed object entity Foo implemented by class Foo.  Foo contains a property BOOL isFoo that is implemented by class Foo but is not backed by an attribute (ie. not part of the schema for entity Foo).  Now using isFoo as a condition in a predicate for NSArrayController works just fine.  One would assume this means that the predicate is applied to the object after it has been fetched, hence hitting the object class.  However, on iOS, use of the same predicate causes an NSInvalidArgumentException of isFoo not found.  On iOS, the predicate appears to be evaluated on the NSSQLEntity object prior to creating the Foo object.

It takes a rather specific cross-platform project to show this, but I have yet to find documentation that illuminates this difference.

Answer (score 0):

In my specific case, the property in question is just a wrapper around an attribute that exists in the entity so I can modify my predicate specifically for iOS.  In the general case, however, this could be a major limitation of NSFetchedResultsController.